# Has anyone had any success in re-creating the office experience/environment remotely?

Tags: work-environment, telecommute, remote-work

I'm interested to learn more about any software/platforms/tools that people have been using while remote working to try and re-create the office experience eg. using platforms for a virtual replication of the office ‘space’ or ways to make people feel less 'alone' when WFH? Perhaps some way to help those spontaneous chats or 'watercooler' conversations to happen more easily by keeping video calls open in the background? Has anyone had any successes in this area?

I'd be interested to understand how you've used them and the benefits/drawbacks etc?

Thanks

Comment: Are you just talking specifically about social interaction? How about teleconference during lunch or other meals? Arrange teleconference team-building activities before/after hours? Or go on YouTube and play ambient office sounds?

Comment: Is this a research project you are doing?

Comment: You are asking a bunch of questions at once, some of which are clearly off topic.  Please take a look at the help center for guidance on what sort of questions are on topic here and consider editing this down to a single focus.  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Welcome and good luck!

Comment: Put pictures of the office on the walls of your room at home

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you may want to check out https://www.sococo.com/why-sococo/ (I just saw it on another recent question).

Answer (score 0):

To answer in part, one suggestion:

run a bi-weekly/occasional virtual "coffee/tea break" for say, 20 minutes. It can be optional and drop in/drop out, with no specific agenda or topic, but generally just to chat. This could be run using any video conferencing software (e.g. zoom, skype, webex etc). I've found these mimic the coffee break type discussions quite well. For some, this may be the only time they hear other people's voices that day; some people may really benefit from listening/having the discussion in the background, rather than chatting themselves. I've seen this be successful for a team of around 20 invited, with a varying group of 5 or 6 people joining a couple of times a week.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much of recreating it is but as several people are back in the office and I am working from home I am using google meet to call 1 person from my room and basically are on the call for full 8h of work. It seems as I am in the room with other people, the mic and speakers of the person in the office is quite good as I am able to hear a person from other side and I am also heard clearly. I am not able to go to the kitchen and chat by the cooler but it actually really helps me not feel totally on my own and almost as if I am in the office with them.

When most of us where working from home we make 3-4 person calls and it also worked even without muting the mic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zefiryn, any chance that I could chat to you more about this? I'm a researcher who's carrying out a study on this topic and looking for people who might be interested in taking part in a short interview for this research? Perhaps I could drop you an email? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I will be of much help but sure, you can write to arturro2@poczta.fm

Answer (score 0):

The difference between being in office and being remote, as pertinent to your question, is **accessibility**. In the office you can walk over/lean over/shout out to a coworker to get their attention/talk to them/distract them, in a virtual setting you have to schedule a meeting via email or an instant messenger.

The strategies I've seen used and used myself revolve around **producing more frequent interactions** to replace the absence of natural interactions that occur in an office setting:

- More meetings in general. Since we *only* talk to each other in meetings, we need more meetings to compensate for the ad hoc interactions we no longer have.
- More idle chat in meetings when waiting for people to join etc. This happens in regular in office setting as well, but in the current environment this is actually  a welcome thing I would say.
- More frequent team/company-wide meetings.
- Virtual lunches where people basically chat for an hour about any topic they want.
- More time dedicated to workplace-appropriate personal questions like "what did you do last weekend" in our scheduled meetings.
- More frequent surveys on the general state of things, equipment needs, etc.
- I personally try to provide positive feedback whenever I can to everyone I work with, both to lift everyone's spirits and because there is less of an opportunity to hear someone say "that's great" at their desk.